# Xcode won't detect files included from main in included file

Tags: c++, xcode, build, include

here is the structure of my program:

```
// File: main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
#include "do.cpp"

int main()
{
   doit();
}

// File: do.cpp
void doit()
{
   cout<<sqrt(2)<<endl;
}
```

When I do
    g++ main.cpp

Everything goes fine. Now, if I open this as an Xcode project (I have chosen "Command line utility" as project type) and try to just build and run, it keeps saying: 
    Use of undeclared identifier sqrt
    Unknown type name 'ostream'

What should I be supposed to do? Did I do something wrong?

Thank you very much!

Matteo

Comment: Not joking.... But have you tried closing and reopening the IDE? XCode has been know to cause problems....

Comment: Uh... yes! I did it five or six times. (Seven now). Build keeps failing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
#include "do.cpp"
```

but instead put that "`do.cpp`" file in the same Xcode project, alongside your main.m or main.cpp file.

And when you want to build from the command line, you can do:

```
g++ main.cpp do.cpp -o mytesttool
```

which would create the command line tool named "mytesttool".

Comment: Well, I did: I mean, first I created the project, and it created main.cpp for me. Then I created a new file with new -> file -> empty file -> do.cpp. It automatically added it to my project, I think.. or not?

Comment: Yes, compiling via command line works, I only wanted it to work directly from within Xcode, but I can live without it...

Comment: doing the "new" -> "file" -> empty file -> do.cpp thing ***is*** the correct thing to do, yes; and it's automatically added to the project.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is quite simple actually. You probably added both files to the project. Xcode tries to compile each file into an object file and then link them together.

When it tries to compile do.cpp it doesn't find the definition of cout because iostream is not included and neither math.h for sqrt, as part of do.cpp.

That file compiles fine when compiled as part of main.cpp, because it is included in the file and it finds iostream and math.h and also the using declaration.

Anyway if you remove do.cpp from the project (just the reference) everything should compile as expected.

**The right way without a header file**

```
// File: main.cpp

void doit();  // declare the function

int main()
{
   doit();
}

// File: do.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void doit()
{
   cout<<sqrt(2)<<endl;
}
```

**The right way with a header file**

```
// File do.h
#ifndef __DO_H_
#define __DO_H_
void doit();
#endif  // __DO_H_

// File: main.cpp

#include "do.h"

int main()
{
   doit();
}

// File: do.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "do.h"

using namespace std;

void doit()
{
   cout<<sqrt(2)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Well...! It actually worked! But now I don't have that file on Xcode any more. How do I edit it etc?

Comment: you can't have both! if you want the file as part of Xcode then do it the right way.
remove the #include "do.cpp" from main.cpp and add the proper includes to do.cpp

Comment: But I want to do it the right way! Only I don't know what the right way is!

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hope that now it is clear what the right way looks like.

Answer (score 0):

When making the new file, I forgot to de-check the "target" selection, so that when it tried to build the project it tried to build all the single files and then link them together. By disabling the "target", I got it to work.